# How to animate the width with slide effect (jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, width, slide

How do I animate the width with a slide effect to the right?

Here's my code:

```
$(".toggle").click(function(){
  $(".wrapper").animate({ width: "80%" });
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$(".toggle").click(function () {
    $(".wrapper").animate({
        width: "80%"
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        specialEasing: {
            width: 'linear'
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gLEd4/)

Comment: One more question, how can i stop it from going to the top of the page when clicking it?

Comment: Is the `toggle` element is a button or anchor? If an anchor you need to use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)..

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#go").click(function(){
  $("#block").animate({
  width: "70%"
  }, 1500 );
});
```